# When I try to use use align in my AS3 textfield, I get a weird error

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So I'm trying to use align to centralize the text in my textfield

```
var inputFieldOne:TextField= new TextField();
        inputFieldOne.width= 150;
        inputFieldOne.height= 50;
        inputFieldOne.x= 180;
        inputFieldOne.border= true;
        inputFieldOne.type= "input";
        inputFieldOne.restrict= "0-9";
        inputFieldOne.maxChars= 1;
        inputFieldOne.background= true;
        inputFieldOne.backgroundColor= 0x00FF00;
        inputFieldOne.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        inputFieldOne.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("verdana", 45);
```

and I get this error:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property align through a reference with static type flash.text:TextField.
```

help?

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` does not have an `align` property.  You may be confusing it with `TextFormat` which does have the property.

Try the following:

```
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("verdana", 45);
textFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER:

var inputFieldOne:TextField= new TextField();
    inputFieldOne.width= 150;
    inputFieldOne.height= 50;
    inputFieldOne.x= 180;
    inputFieldOne.border= true;
    inputFieldOne.type= "input";
    inputFieldOne.restrict= "0-9";
    inputFieldOne.maxChars= 1;
    inputFieldOne.background= true;
    inputFieldOne.backgroundColor= 0x00FF00;
    inputFieldOne.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
```